# Open Source Library that read Shapefile for Reverse Geocoding

Tags: reverse-geocoding, shapefile

I am looking for an open source library that enables us to read/query shapefile (ESRI shapefiles). 
Basically I have an application that performs a reverse-geocoding similar task.
The application takes inputs as latitude/longitude and it must return corresponding zipcode.

Therefore I am looking for a library which will basically read the given shapefile and will answer to the queries like (lat/long -> zipcode). I have with me the Zipcode Tabulation Area TIGER shapefile which is made available by US Census Data.
Does anyone know of any such a library ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

take a look at GeoTools: http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/quickstart/index.html